# TinyMCE textarea not editable

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, wysiwyg

I have integrated tinymce in my form, inside a modal.

```
$form['myid_templates_editor']['text-modal'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',           
    '#format' => 'full_html',
    '#prefix' => <div id="first_modal">
    '#suffix' => </div>         
)};
```

The JavaScript code I am using is the following.

```
jQuery('#first_modal').dialog('open');
```

It was working well, but when I open again another modal while the first modal is still open, the tinymce text area was somewhat disabled and  not editable. Why?

```
jQuery('#second_modal').dialog('open');
```

What shall I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.the-modal').bind('shown', function() {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'mce-<?=$reply["id"]?>');
    });

    $('.the-modal').bind('hide', function() {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'mce-<?=$reply["id"]?>');
    });
</script>
```

It was a bug and I found a solution [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/549).